# Where is the error? Application of FTC

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, solution-verification, fake-proofs

Please, I need a help to see the error on this argument:$$\int_0^tf(a)g(t-a)da=\int_0^tf(t-a)g(a)da\implies$$

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_0^tf(a)g(t-a)da=\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_0^tf(t-a)g(a)da\implies$$

$$f(t)g(0)=f(0)g(t)$$

If $f(0)=g(0)=k\neq 0$, então

$$f(t)=g(t)\forall t\in\Bbb R.$$

It is obviously incorrect, but I could not find the error.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply FTC here -- you have to use the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). This is because not only are the bounds changing, but the inside of the integral itself is changing as well. Contrast this with $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xxt\;dt=\frac{t^2}2,$$ not $xt$ as a naive application of FTC would entail.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: 23 answers in 2 hours. This is impressive.

Comment: Actually $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xtdt=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^3}{2}=\frac{3x^2}{2}$, while any naïve FTC use would still try to claim the result is a function of $x$ alone.